# Simple SQL command not properly ended

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have the following query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM DELUSR.AGREEMENT AS agreement 
WHERE agreement.MASTER_AGGREMENT_ID = 4;
```

After trying to run it, I get this error:

> Error code 933, SQL state 42000:
>   ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
>   Line 1, column 1
>   Execution finished after 0 s, 1 error(s) occurred.

I am not sure how to decode this error message. The statement looks fine to me. Any insights into whats wrong with it?

Comment: try removing the semi-colon at the end

Comment: No effect, same error :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Oracle accepts no AS for table aliases:

```
SELECT * FROM DELUSR.AGREEMENT agreement WHERE agreement.MASTER_AGGREMENT_ID = 4;
```

Comment: Yeah, strange enough that Oracle doesn't support it - be it for standard compliance or the mere reason of better readability.