# Select columns after validating the existence in ALL_TAB_COLUMNS

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to combine below into a single statement -

1. Look for the existence of a column (or list of columns) in ALL_TAB_COLUMNS.
2. If a column exists, it should be included in the SELECT column list.
3. Execute the constructed SELECT statement and return the result.

Table -

```
CREATE TABLE SCHEMA.TEST (id int PRIMARY KEY, name varchar(20), address varchar(20));
```

The below query does not work for me.

```
SELECT c.* FROM 
    (SELECT column_name FROM all_tab_columns where 
        owner = 'SCHEMA' AND table_name = 'TEST' and column_name IN ('ID', 'NAME')) AS c
```

** Removed `AS` as suggested by @MTO -

```
SELECT c.* FROM 
    (SELECT column_name FROM all_tab_columns where 
        owner = 'SCHEMA' AND table_name = 'TEST' and column_name IN ('ID', 'NAME')) c
```

Comment: Remove `AS` as Oracle does not allow the `AS` keyword before a table alias. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/sQmHz4va)

Comment: Thanks @MTO I have fixed the query. But the question remains the same. Once I have the column name, I want to combine the result with the SELECT statement to fetch the column value from the table.

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of [LINK] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31415750/simple-sql-command-not-properly-ended)